# If $f(x × f(y)) = \dfrac{f ( x) }y , x, y \in \mathbb R , y \ne 0$, then prove that $f(x) . f (1 /x) = 1$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> If $f(x × f(y)) = \dfrac{f ( x) }y , x, y \in \mathbb R , y \ne 0$, then prove that $f(x) . f (1 /x)  = 1$

Putting $x=0$, I get $$f(0)=\frac{f(0)}y$$

From this I conclude $y=1\;\forall x\in \mathbb R$. Is this a correct conclusion?

Therefore, the given equation becomes $$f(x\times f(1))=f(x)$$

From this I conclude $f(1)=1$. Is this correct?

But not able to obtain $f\left(\dfrac1x\right)$.

Comment: Well, it could be that $f(0)=0$ of course.  The claim "$y=1\,\forall x\in \mathbb R$ " doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'd assume this is meant to be correct for all $x, y$ so you can't conclude nothing about $y$ you can about $f(0)$ though.

Comment: Should say:  the function $f(x)=0\,\forall x$ satisfies your functional equation, so you won't be able to show what you want without some additional assumptions.  Maybe try assuming that $f(x)$ is never $0$.

Comment: @lulu thanks. You are right. $y=1$ doesn't make sense. But why do you say $f(x)=0$ satisfies for all $x$?

Comment: Because your equation becomes $0=0$ which is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have observed $f(1) = 1$, we have
$$f(1\cdot f(y)) = \frac{f(1)}{y} = \frac{1}{y} \\
f(f(\color{fuchsia}y)) = \frac{1}{\color{fuchsia}y}$$
Then
$$f(x)f\left(\frac1x\right) \overset{1/x = f(f(x))}{=} f(x)f(f(\color{fuchsia}{f(x)})) = f(x)\frac{1}{\color{fuchsia}{f(x)}} = 1$$

Comment: Nice answer though I think there's more justification needed for $f(1)=1$ (from what the OP did).

Comment: @kingW3 Sure, I will let the OP observe it more rigorously then.

Comment: I attempted the question again. Couldn't solve it. So, went through your solution again and grasped how beautiful your answer is! Thankyou.

Comment: @aarbee You are welcome.